# Different output with the atom script package and python 3

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, ascii, atom-editor

I work with the atom editor and the *script* package on macOS Mojave.

I create a file which contains a print with a german Umlaut:

```
 print(hellö)
```

When I execute the file directly in Atom, the following error message appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/hambert/runScriptAtom.py", line 1, in <module>
print("hell\xf6")
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
[Finished in 0.16s]
```

in terminal

```
hambert$ python3 /Users/hambert/runScriptAtom.py 
hellö
```

I checked the version with

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

and it's exactly the same

Comment: There's probably a setting for the encoding of Atom's console. Find it and set it to UTF-8 instead of ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding

```
  PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8
```

to the environment variables in the run options